# Xcode 6 so many simulators confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have installed new Xcode 6. In the image attached, you can see there are so many simulators of same version e.g iPad 2, iPad Air, iPhone 4S, iPhone 5 etc but in () you see they have different identifiers.

Whats the difference between different types of same simulator?

Is there a way where I can rename to make them more understandable.

Thank you

[image: So many simulators with same name but different ids]

Comment: Have you still got all the old SDKs installed?

Comment: Not the olds Sdks, but I copied old simulators from xcode 5 to this new Xcode 6

Comment: seems totally wrong. there should be 4 or 5.

Comment: see thats the issue then

Comment: but I removed those and still the list was same.

Comment: should I move this xcode to trash and install the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got so many by copying old ones to the new xcode . which is not really supported.

therefore there is no way of renaming them

---

to get rid of them, deletion isn't enough. trash xcode, its prefs, shared data and THEN make a clean install

Comment: should I move this xcode to trash and install the new one? it will fix the issue. right?

Comment: no as its data is not in its app bundle. see my edit . you have to remove it completely

Comment: Removed it all is well now. Thanks :)